# How to locally edit an already deployed function in Azure Functions (Python)?

Tags: python, azure-functions

After having worked on a Azure Functions application, i have now deployed the app and had it running for a while. Now I want to continue my work on another computer, however I cant seem to identify any way to download the source code in either VS Code nor Azure Portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For python function we can not download the content from Azure portal or VS code. It is in read-only mode.

[image]

**Workaround:**

1.Copy your project to another computer.

2.Create a new project on another computer and copy the main files from azure portal.

**host.json** and **requirements.txt** files from **App files**.

[image]

***init*.py** and **function.json** files from **Code+Test**.

[image]

Comment: That's what i feared. Alright, time to get the code into Github i guess- Thanks!